# php fastest way to search array of objects to find needle and index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

**PHP version: 5.3**

In Wordpress, I have an array of all the posts in a category having this format.

```
array
  0 => 
      public 'ID' => int 360
      public 'post_title' => string 'Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice' 
  1 => 
      public 'ID' => int 371
      public 'post_title' => string 'Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens'
... =>
```

Knowing the 'post_title' of the current post, what is the most efficient way using "post_title" as a needle to search the array and find it's index?

Comment: There is an [array_column compatible function for those of us on versions of PHP < 5.5.](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP 7+**

Native functions are usually the fastest because they can be optimized inside the PHP interpreter:

```
array_search($post_title, array_column($yourArray, 'post_title'));
```

`array_column` is turning your array of objects into a simple array of index => post title.  `array_search` is then scanning that array for the index matching the title you are searching for.

---

**PHP 5.3**

*PHP 5.3 is unsupported and should no longer be used*, but if you have no choice, `array_column` is not available, so I would use:

```
array_search($post_title, 
     array_map(function($object) {
             return $object->post_title;
         },
         $yourArray
     )
);
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver `array_column` works on arrays of objects. From the docs: `If an array of objects is provided, then public properties can be directly pulled.`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: As of PHP 7, which you might be lucky if the OP even has >= 5.5 that includes `array_column()` :-)

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Sorry, I should have specified the version of PHP, 5.3. Is there a method I could use before 5.5, that is as efficient as array_column?

Comment: Works great. Thank you